# Is there anyway to select a custom image/icon in Indesign CC for use in lists other than by making a custom glyph typeface?

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

Trying to use a heptagon (7-sided polygon) in place of a dash in a list style for a project in Indesign CC 2015. There doesn't appear to be a simple way to add it to the available icon choices without it being in a font. I'd rather not have to manually place all 200 some heptagons, thus the goal of trying to do it with a bulleted list style. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is probably to make your icon a font. This can be done using a script by @jongware. He can do a better job of explaining it than I can. It's something that I have on my radar for the next time I need to create glyphs, so I haven't used it yet. There's a free trial or basic version. The script and more details can be found on indiscripts.com: http://www.indiscripts.com/category/projects/IndyFont.

Comment: Thanks for the mention! To create a single glyph font all you need is the demo. Marc Autret's web page, and the freely downloadable manual contain all information to create a single bullet.